# JS: Extract only unique attribute objects from array

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on developing an API, where I need to make a function to extract "completely" unique objects, i.e. no attribute match in any of the objects.

I have an array of objects of fixed schema like: (*Modified this*)

```js
let arr = [{
      "a": "a1",
      "b": "b1",
      "c": "c1",
      "d": "d1",
      "e": "e1"
    },
    {
      "a": "a2",
      "b": "b2",
      "c": "c2",
      "d": "d2",
      "e": "e2"
    },
    {
      "a": "a3",
      "b": "b3",
      "c": "c2", // matching attribute
      "d": "d3",
      "e": "e3"
    },
    // values in previous object should not affect this unique object:
    {
      "a": "a3",
      "b": "b3",
      "c": "c3",
      "d": "d3",
      "e": "e3"
    },
    // … more objects here, maximum 200 * 33 objects
  ]
```

And I want the result as:

```js
[
  {
    "a": "a1",
    "b": "b1",
    "c": "c1",
    "d": "d1",
    "e": "e1"
  },
  {
    "a": "a2",
    "b": "b2",
    "c": "c2",
    "d": "d2",
    "e": "e2"
  },
  {
    "a": "a3",
    "b": "b3",
    "c": "c3",
    "d": "d3",
    "e": "e3"
  },
  // … 
]
```

In case of matching attribute, the object which is encountered first in the array shall be kept and the other be discarded. Different properties will never have overlapping values.

My current implementation (*wrong*, see comments):

```
for (let i in arr[0]) {
    let map = new Map();
    arr = arr.filter(obj => map.get(obj[i]) ? false : map.set(obj[i], true));
}
console.log(arr);
```

I̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶b̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶(̶m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶e̶f̶f̶i̶c̶i̶e̶n̶t̶)̶    What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What about `"c": "d2"`, is that possible? Would that be a match, in which case this dupe should be filtered out? Or will the different properties never have overlapping values?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Different properties will never have overlapping values. Mentioned that in an edit.

Comment: @brc-dd so that suggests you only need to evaluate values

Comment: @Mike In the answer that you had recently posted, you were using a JSON object `cache`. In CertainPerformance's answer he is using `Set` to store those values. Which one do you think should result in better performance?

Comment: @brc-dd my answer was invalid because it held retained the key in `cache` that discarded subsequent objects. I've since fixed this.  To answer your question, I think performance of `Set` vs object literal is nuanced.  Here's an old test (https://gist.github.com/Chunlin-Li/2606bd813df88eaeee2d), which shows the object literal faster. I imagine node has since been tuned and as comments show it's dependent on the value being captured.  I use object literals out of habit and preference (I find it easier to read)

Comment: @Mike Yeah actually even my approach was wrong for that case, though I wasn't getting an issue because of the data I was feeding to the function. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be faster to only track values, rather than looking up values by key, especially for each iteration.

Below uses one global `cache` to track values and a local cache (i.e. `added`) to provide cleanup when an object isn't unique (so values aren't retained in the `cache`).

```js
const data = getData()
const cache = {}

const results = data.filter(obj => {
  const added = {}
  for (const v of Object.values(obj)){
    if( cache[v] ){
      Object.keys(added).forEach(v=>delete cache[v])
      return false
    }
    else
      added[v] = cache[v] = 1
  }
  return true
});

console.log(results);

/* ===================================================== */
function getData() {
  return [{
      "a": "a1",
      "b": "b1",
      "c": "c1",
      "d": "d1",
      "e": "e1"
    },
    {
      "a": "a2",
      "b": "b2",
      "c": "c2",
      "d": "d2",
      "e": "e2"
    },
    {
      "a": "a3",
      "b": "b3",
      "c": "c2", // matching attribute
      "d": "d3",
      "e": "e3"
    },
    // values in previous object should not affect this unique object:
    {
      "a": "a3",
      "b": "b3",
      "c": "c3",
      "d": "d3",
      "e": "e3"
    },
    // … more objects here, maximum 200 * 33 objects
  ];
}
```

---

## Option 2

Instead of adding to cache and then removing those values when not unique, it might be worthwhile to:

1. only check `cache` & `added` upfront and add to `added` in the loop
2. add `added` to `cache` after the loop (only reached if the entire object is unique)

That way you don't have to go through and do cleanup, which could be expensive if there are a lot of values.  Any performance tuning (optimizations) depends on the data (size and type) and might require different adjustments to best suit the data.

That would look like:

```js
const data = getData()
const cache = {}

const results = data.filter(obj => {
  const added = {}
  for (const v of Object.values(obj)){
    if( cache[v] || added[v])
      return false
    else
      added[v] = 1     // store in local cache
  }
  Object.keys(added).forEach(v=>cache[v]=1)   // store in permanent cache
  return true
});

console.log(results);

/* ===================================================== */
function getData() {
  return [{
      "a": "a1",
      "b": "b1",
      "c": "c1",
      "d": "d1",
      "e": "e1"
    },
    {
      "a": "a2",
      "b": "b2",
      "c": "c2",
      "d": "d2",
      "e": "e2"
    },
    {
      "a": "a3",
      "b": "b3",
      "c": "c2", // matching attribute
      "d": "d3",
      "e": "e3"
    },
    // values in previous object should not affect this unique object:
    {
      "a": "a3",
      "b": "b3",
      "c": "c3",
      "d": "d3",
      "e": "e3"
    },
    // … more objects here, maximum 200 * 33 objects
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a Set of all values found so far. When checking a new object, check if any of its values are included in the set: if so, exclude it, otherwise add all values to the set:

```js
let arr = [{
      "a": "a1",
      "b": "b1",
      "c": "c1",
      "d": "d1",
      "e": "e1"
    },
    {
      "a": "a2",
      "b": "b2",
      "c": "c2",
      "d": "d2",
      "e": "e2"
    },
    {
      "a": "a3",
      "b": "b3",
      "c": "c2", // matching attribute
      "d": "d3",
      "e": "e3"
    },
    // values in previous object should not affect this unique object:
    {
      "a": "a3",
      "b": "b3",
      "c": "c3",
      "d": "d3",
      "e": "e3"
    },
    // … more objects here, maximum 200 * 33 objects
];
const valuesFound = new Set();
const uniques = arr.filter((obj) => {
  const vals = Object.values(obj);
  if (vals.some(val => valuesFound.has(val))) {
    return false;
  }
  for (const val of vals) {
    valuesFound.add(val);
  }
  return true;
});
console.log(uniques);
```

This has the lowest computational complexity possible - there aren't any nested loops except the `.some`, and that `.some`'s callback is `O(n)`, since it's using `Set.prototype.has`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more concise. The moment something returns false `every` will shortcircuit.

```
arr.filter(function(o){
    var that = this,
        vals = Object.values(o),
        pass = vals.every(v=>!~that.indexOf(v));
    return pass && that.push.apply(that,vals);
},[])
```

Change the lamba to regular func and it work everywhere, not only ES6.

Answer (score 0):

it is verified :)

```
     let ids=[]
     let filtered_arr=arr.filter(ar=>{
      if(ids.includes(ar.c)){ 
        return false
       }    
       else{
        ids.push(ar.c);
        return true;}  
     }  
      )
    console.log(filtered_arr);
```